# How to retrieve secret from Azure Key Vault from console application

Tags: authentication, console-application, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault

I've studied the [Azure Key Vault developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide), many lined resources and quite some questions here on SO but get a list of exceptions starting with *Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException* still. All attempts from *DefaultAzureCredential* fail. Here are the two lines of code:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri($"https://kv-xxx.vault.azure.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecret("xxx-api-key");
```

I cannot use the recommended 'managed identity for applications'. The application runs on a server in the context of a service account. Initially I was under the impression all the authentication details would be passed along fully transparently, as this is the case for other resources. I verified via Azure portal that the account has proper permissions to read the secret.

I hope this short description of the scenario allows someone to guide me in the right direction anyway. It feels like the stack trace and additional arbitrary information on hand do not contribute to finding a solution.

To summarize, what I want is to execute a console application on a remote machine with a service account that retrieves a secret from Azure Key Vault, so I do not have to put this secret in the source code or any kind of config file. I was able to create the secret and permit the user read access. **I fail to authenticate to Key Vault in code though.**

Cheers and Happy New Year to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the secret value, create an Azure AD/Microsoft Entra ID application:

[image]

To get the secret value, the **application must have Key Vault Secrets User role** :

*Go to your Key vault -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Select Key Vault Secrets User -> Select members -> Select your application -> Review + assign*

[image]

**Now use the below code and the secret value will be retrieved successfully:**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var clientId = "ClientIDofApp";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecretofApp";
var vaultUri = new Uri("https://rukkvs.vault.azure.net/");
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var secretname = "testsecret";

var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri, credential);
var secret = client.GetSecret(secretname);

Console.WriteLine($"secret value for the secret {secretname} is {secret.Value.Value}");
```

[image]

- If your key vault is configured as **"Azure role-based access control"**, then assign Key Vault Secrets User role to the application.
- If your key vault is configured as **"Vault access policy"**, then you have to create access policy selecting Secret permissions and assigning it to application.

Comment: Hats off Rukmini! Are you actually saying, there is no way to read the secret w/o registering an application in Azure and using the client secret generated for authentication? There is no way to authenticate with the user account executing the program? It feels like I'm going round in circles. With this approach, I replace the secret I stored safely in KV in the source code with the client secret to access the KV. Either way I keep having "passwords" in the code...

Comment: You can make use of interactive flows  to user sign-in but even that needs Azure ad application

Comment: You can make use of ROPC flow which doesn't require passing secret but that is not recommended by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: Thank you for the reminder @SPT. I'm still considering and studying the reply and getting it to work for me.

Comment: I've just accepted the answer from Rukmini. It did not solve my problem but all the information provided are accurate and helpful. After all, Azure key vault might just not be the correct choice for an on-premise console app.